# Smaller version of the Mega

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm currently working on a Arduino Mega (GPS + IMU + SD card logging + BT). I need the Mega for extra memory and serial port. 
I would like to transition to something with a smaller form factor now. I need help with suggestions for a smaller form factor board/version of Mega.

Any suggestions?
I can't really find anything.

The only small size yet meeting requirements (in terms of memory) option seems to be a [Microduino](https://www.microduino.cc/module/view?id=53d7037cb6c69d00003ede53) - 
but I'm not whether all the libraries (SDfat etc.) will work on this.

Comment: It should be possible to make something smaller with an ATmega2560, but realistically most of that market is claimed by little ARM cortex boards which are yet more capable - Teensy for example.

Comment: @O.K. Microduino appears to be a company, not a single product. What board did you go with? Also, you link appears to be broken.

Comment: @Cerin we eventually used a Teensy 3.2... btw this post was 2+ years old, so Microduino may have changed the product links

Comment: @O.K. The Teensy does indeed look exactly like what you described. I was looking for something like that myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ATmega1284P provides 128kB of flash, 16kB of SRAM, 4kB of EEPROM, and 2 USARTs in a 40/44/49-pin package. [Mighty 1284P](https://github.com/maniacbug/mighty-1284p) provides Arduino support for the '1284P.

There aren't too many actual boards that feature it, but it [can be used very easily](https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/arduino-on-atmega1284p-4/) on a breadboard or custom PCB with a [programmer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3906/how-do-i-write-an-arduino-program-to-an-avr-chip-without-the-arduino-bootloader).

Comment: thanks Ignacio. I think I will go for the Microduino (link in my ques), which as mentioned by Nathan uses the ATmega1284 you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The link uses the same chip that Ignacio recommended.  The libraries will need some minor edits, but many of the standard ones do have a 1284P fork.  It is mostly just redoing pin assignments, or adding the 1284P to the board definitions.  I am working on a similar project and have gotten the 1284P to work with SDfat, a bunch of standard GPS libraries, and TinyGPS++ .

Comment: Thanks Nathan, good to know someone has tried using 1284 with the existing libs. I want to avoid any major/complex work in porting libs; your comment is helpful here. Also, if you don't mind, can you share exactly which 1284 board you are using?

Comment: I am using a breadboard version documented here: https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/arduino-on-atmega1284p-4/  The included zip file has some already adapted libraries but adapting the others wasn't too hard.  Basically you just have to search 1284P and library for the major ones.

Comment: I like Jack Christensen's Might Mini design so much I sell it assembled on eBay, username hexinverter. That 2K of RAM in Nanos and the like is just painful. Anyone interested in making their own can find the design and BOM here: https://github.com/JChristensen/mini1284 and a boards.txt for 1.0.5/6 here: https://github.com/JChristensen/mighty-1284p ... all derived from and mentioned in the ManiacBug post and discussed at arduino.cc forums.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Mega2560-CORE" on ebay.

Some information:
http://www.inhaos.com/product_info.php?products_id=88